# How to navigate from one Lightning Web Component to another Lightning Web Component in COMMUNITY?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I am new to LWC Development. I saw a couple of articles on how to navigate from one LWC to another LWC. One was using another lightning component and lightning:isUrlAddressable and another was using http://instance url.com/one/one.app# in the url.

I wanted to use the second option but then i remembered one app is not supported in community. Is there any workaround for this. I wanted to build the entire logic using LWC only if possible. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Do you need to pass parameters from one LWC to another on navigation?  If not, this might just be a matter of having one LWC on one Communities Page and the other LWC on another Communities Page.  Then linking between them could be achieved with an HTML link (`a`) element and a relative URL `href`, or by setting `window.location` in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.